# ASP C#: TreeView and LinkButton

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, linkbutton, asplinkbutton

I work on a web projects in ASP C#, in my MasterPage i have a TreeView  and two LinkButton which Collapse and Expand the nodes of the TreeView, both LinkBuutons work properly but after it's Expand or Collapse the TreeView, it's create others TreeViews.

Here is a piece of my masterPage

```
        <body>     
            <form runat="server">  
        ... //I cut a part of code 
         <table id="Principal">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="Menu" class="auto-style1">
                               <div style="width : 320px; height : 700px; overflow : auto; ">
                                    <asp:HyperLink Text="Accueil" NavigateUrl="~/Views/Accueil.aspx" runat="server"/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnDevAll" Text="Tout développer" OnClick="devAll_Click" runat="server" /> - <asp:LinkButton ID="btnRedAll" Text="Tout réduire" OnClick="redAll_Click" runat="server" />
                                    <br/>

                                  <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewMenu" runat="server"  ParentNodeStyle-ForeColor="Black" ParentNodeStyle-ImageUrl="~/images/folderclose.gif" >
                                </asp:TreeView>
                               </div>

                            </td>
                            <td id="Content" style="vertical-align: top; overflow:visible;">                    
                                 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
                                 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
    ... //I cut a part of code 
    </form>
</body>
```

And now functions to collapse and expand the TreeView

```
 protected void redAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeViewMenu.CollapseAll();

        }

        protected void devAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeViewMenu.ExpandAll();

        }
```

Thanks to anyone who will try to solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean it creates other treeviews?

Comment: I don't understand what it does but  for example when i click on LinkButtton to Collapse, my TreeViewMenu reduced properly and after it's creates an other treeview with the same nodes of my TreeViewMenu under it.

Comment: If you are populating the treeview in a Page_Load event you will need ensure it's inside an if (!IsPostBack)